# How to Modify/PUSH AVD Host File from Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: android, windows, command-line, adb, host

Following the directions found here "[Testing Local Web Sites with the Android Emulator](https://mattormeeple.com/2015/09/03/testing-local-web-sites-with-the-android-emulator/)", I've been successful up until `Make your changes to the hosts file and then save it back to the AVD`. In other words, I'm unable to push my modified host file back to the AVD. The directions in the article are for Mac, so I've converted the command lines to windows.

The Mac command referenced in the article is this...

```
$ ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 push ~/Desktop/hosts /system/etc/hosts
```

Which I've translated to Windows as this...

```
$ adb –s emulator-5554 push C:\Users\(username)\Downloads\hosts /system/etc/hosts
```

Note:

- for the windows command, I'm already in the C:/(path_to_android_sdk)/platform-tools/ directory, where adb lives
- The (username) in my local path is a placeholder for my actual username
- The modified host file does exist at the path specified.

When I run the adb command to push the host file back to the AVD, the file is not pushed and I see this output in the terminal...

```
C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb -s emu
lator-5554 push C:\Users\(username)\Downloads\hosts /system/etc/hosts
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
Revision e02fe72a18c3-android

 -a                            - directs adb to listen on all interfaces for a c
onnection
 -d                            - directs command to the only connected USB devic
e
                                 returns an error if more than one USB device is
 present.
 -e                            - directs command to the only running emulator.
                                 returns an error if more than one emulator is r
unning.
 -s <specific device>          - directs command to the device or emulator with
the given
                                 serial number or qualifier. Overrides ANDROID_S
ERIAL
                                 environment variable.
 -p <product name or path>     - simple product name like 'sooner', or
                                 a relative/absolute path to a product
                                 out directory like 'out/target/product/sooner'.

                                 If -p is not specified, the ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT

                                 environment variable is used, which must
                                 be an absolute path.
 -H                            - Name of adb server host (default: localhost)
 -P                            - Port of adb server (default: 5037)
 devices [-l]                  - list all connected devices
                                 ('-l' will also list device qualifiers)
 connect <host>[:<port>]       - connect to a device via TCP/IP
                                 Port 5555 is used by default if no port number
is specified.
 disconnect [<host>[:<port>]]  - disconnect from a TCP/IP device.
                                 Port 5555 is used by default if no port number
is specified.
                                 Using this command with no additional arguments

                                 will disconnect from all connected TCP/IP devic
es.

device commands:
  adb push <local>... <remote>
                               - copy files/dirs to device
  adb pull [-a] <remote>... <local>
                               - copy files/dirs from device
                                 (-a preserves file timestamp and mode)
  adb sync [ <directory> ]     - copy host->device only if changed
                                 (-l means list but don't copy)
  adb shell [-e escape] [-n] [-Tt] [-x] [command]
                               - run remote shell command (interactive shell if
no command given)
                                 (-e: choose escape character, or "none"; defaul
t '~')
                                 (-n: don't read from stdin)
                                 (-T: disable PTY allocation)
                                 (-t: force PTY allocation)
                                 (-x: disable remote exit codes and stdout/stder
r separation)
  adb emu <command>            - run emulator console command
  adb logcat [ <filter-spec> ] - View device log
  adb forward --list           - list all forward socket connections.
                                 the format is a list of lines with the followin
g format:
                                    <serial> " " <local> " " <remote> "\n"
  adb forward <local> <remote> - forward socket connections
                                 forward specs are one of:
                                   tcp:<port>
                                   localabstract:<unix domain socket name>
                                   localreserved:<unix domain socket name>
                                   localfilesystem:<unix domain socket name>
                                   dev:<character device name>
                                   jdwp:<process pid> (remote only)
  adb forward --no-rebind <local> <remote>
                               - same as 'adb forward <local> <remote>' but fail
s
                                 if <local> is already forwarded
  adb forward --remove <local> - remove a specific forward socket connection
  adb forward --remove-all     - remove all forward socket connections
  adb reverse --list           - list all reverse socket connections from device

  adb reverse <remote> <local> - reverse socket connections
                                 reverse specs are one of:
                                   tcp:<port>
                                   localabstract:<unix domain socket name>
                                   localreserved:<unix domain socket name>
                                   localfilesystem:<unix domain socket name>
  adb reverse --no-rebind <remote> <local>
                               - same as 'adb reverse <remote> <local>' but fail
s
                                 if <remote> is already reversed.
  adb reverse --remove <remote>
                               - remove a specific reversed socket connection
  adb reverse --remove-all     - remove all reversed socket connections from dev
ice
  adb jdwp                     - list PIDs of processes hosting a JDWP transport

  adb install [-lrtsdg] <file>
                               - push this package file to the device and instal
l it
                                 (-l: forward lock application)
                                 (-r: replace existing application)
                                 (-t: allow test packages)
                                 (-s: install application on sdcard)
                                 (-d: allow version code downgrade (debuggable p
ackages only))
                                 (-g: grant all runtime permissions)
  adb install-multiple [-lrtsdpg] <file...>
                               - push this package file to the device and instal
l it
                                 (-l: forward lock application)
                                 (-r: replace existing application)
                                 (-t: allow test packages)
                                 (-s: install application on sdcard)
                                 (-d: allow version code downgrade (debuggable p
ackages only))
                                 (-p: partial application install)
                                 (-g: grant all runtime permissions)
  adb uninstall [-k] <package> - remove this app package from the device
                                 ('-k' means keep the data and cache directories
)
  adb bugreport [<zip_file>]   - return all information from the device
                                 that should be included in a bug report.

  adb backup [-f <file>] [-apk|-noapk] [-obb|-noobb] [-shared|-noshared] [-all]
[-system|-nosystem] [<packages...>]
                               - write an archive of the device's data to <file>
.
                                 If no -f option is supplied then the data is wr
itten
                                 to "backup.ab" in the current directory.
                                 (-apk|-noapk enable/disable backup of the .apks
 themselves
                                    in the archive; the default is noapk.)
                                 (-obb|-noobb enable/disable backup of any insta
lled apk expansion
                                    (aka .obb) files associated with each applic
ation; the default
                                    is noobb.)
                                 (-shared|-noshared enable/disable backup of the
 device's
                                    shared storage / SD card contents; the defau
lt is noshared.)
                                 (-all means to back up all installed applicatio
ns)
                                 (-system|-nosystem toggles whether -all automat
ically includes
                                    system applications; the default is to inclu
de system apps)
                                 (<packages...> is the list of applications to b
e backed up.  If
                                    the -all or -shared flags are passed, then t
he package
                                    list is optional.  Applications explicitly g
iven on the
                                    command line will be included even if -nosys
tem would
                                    ordinarily cause them to be omitted.)

  adb restore <file>           - restore device contents from the <file> backup
archive

  adb disable-verity           - disable dm-verity checking on USERDEBUG builds
  adb enable-verity            - re-enable dm-verity checking on USERDEBUG build
s
  adb keygen <file>            - generate adb public/private key. The private ke
y is stored in <file>,
                                 and the public key is stored in <file>.pub. Any
 existing files
                                 are overwritten.
  adb help                     - show this help message
  adb version                  - show version num

scripting:
  adb wait-for[-<transport>]-<state>
                               - wait for device to be in the given state:
                                 device, recovery, sideload, or bootloader
                                 Transport is: usb, local or any [default=any]
  adb start-server             - ensure that there is a server running
  adb kill-server              - kill the server if it is running
  adb get-state                - prints: offline | bootloader | device
  adb get-serialno             - prints: <serial-number>
  adb get-devpath              - prints: <device-path>
  adb remount                  - remounts the /system, /vendor (if present) and
/oem (if present) partitions on the device read-write
  adb reboot [bootloader|recovery]
                               - reboots the device, optionally into the bootloa
der or recovery program.
  adb reboot sideload          - reboots the device into the sideload mode in re
covery program (adb root required).
  adb reboot sideload-auto-reboot
                               - reboots into the sideload mode, then reboots au
tomatically after the sideload regardless of the result.
  adb sideload <file>          - sideloads the given package
  adb root                     - restarts the adbd daemon with root permissions
  adb unroot                   - restarts the adbd daemon without root permissio
ns
  adb usb                      - restarts the adbd daemon listening on USB
  adb tcpip <port>             - restarts the adbd daemon listening on TCP on th
e specified port

networking:
  adb ppp <tty> [parameters]   - Run PPP over USB.
 Note: you should not automatically start a PPP connection.
 <tty> refers to the tty for PPP stream. Eg. dev:/dev/omap_csmi_tty1
 [parameters] - Eg. defaultroute debug dump local notty usepeerdns

adb sync notes: adb sync [ <directory> ]
  <localdir> can be interpreted in several ways:

  - If <directory> is not specified, /system, /vendor (if present), /oem (if pre
sent) and /data partitions will be updated.

  - If it is "system", "vendor", "oem" or "data", only the corresponding partiti
on
    is updated.

internal debugging:
  adb reconnect                  Kick current connection from host side and make
 it reconnect.
  adb reconnect device           Kick current connection from device side and ma
ke it reconnect.
environment variables:
  ADB_TRACE                    - Print debug information. A comma separated list
 of the following values
                                 1 or all, adb, sockets, packets, rwx, usb, sync
, sysdeps, transport, jdwp
  ANDROID_SERIAL               - The serial number to connect to. -s takes prior
ity over this if given.
  ANDROID_LOG_TAGS             - When used with the logcat option, only these de
bug tags are printed.
```

Which tells me something went wrong with the syntax. As far as I can tell, the syntax is correct though. Any ideas?

Comment: and your username does not contain a space by any chance?

Comment: good question, no there are no space characters. there is a period though  (e.g. user.name), but as the pull command worked, I don't expect that's an issue at all. Here's the pull command `adb -s emulator-5554 pull /system/etc/hosts C:\Users\(user.name)\Downloads\`

Comment: in your `adb –s` command `-` is replaced by unicode `–`

Comment: good catch! I bet that's the problem. I'll check it out and let you know. Thx